# Is that possible to give the standard functional like duplication record link on trigger addError method?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am creating a trigger to check the duplication record .

```
//Condition 
for(test__c on testObj : Trigger.new)
{
    if(duplicateRecordFound())
    {

       testobj.addError("Duplicate Record Found") // I want to link the duplicate record ID here

    }
}
```

This one is from standard functionality. Any Idea or suggestion ?

[image]

Comment: What's in the `duplicateRecordFound` method?

Comment: It will check the duplicate record and return boolean value

Comment: You could update this method to return a class containing the boolean and the id found.

Comment: Yes. I can return the ID. How do I merge with error method ? Like link

Comment: It depends on the name of the variable returned by the `duplicateRecordFound` method. For example, imagine its name is `duplicatedFound`. And you gave to the Id found returned, the variable name: `DuplicateId`. You can use for example: `testobj.addError("Duplicate Record Found: " + duplicateFound.DuplicateId);`

Answer (score 0):

After a long trial and error this allowed me to show hyper link on the page layout for trigger.addError()

```
  //Condition 
for(test__c on testObj : Trigger.new)
{
    if(duplicateRecordFound())
    {
         testobj.addError('<a href=\"/'+duplicateFound.Id+'\">'+duplicateFound.Name+'</a>'+'Duplicate Record Found',false);  //It gave link as like as standard functionality
    }
 }
```